# How to turn a string into a modified hex representation?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, od

i want to turn a string like

```
AaAa
```

into

a string like this

```
%<41>%<61>%<41>%<61>
```

Simple enough with the programming languages i am familar with, but with bash i can't get get the piping right to do what i am trying to do:

- split string into char array
- turn each char into hex
- wrap each hex value into `%<FF>`
- concat string

this is my current way which gets me half way there:

```
echo -n "AaAa" | od -A n -t x1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are already using `od`,

```
printf "%%<%s>" $(od -A n -t x1<<<"AaAa")
```

For an all-bash without `od`,

```
while read -r -N 1 c; do printf "%%<%02X>" "$( printf "%d" \'$c )"; done <<< AaAa
```

The downside of this approach is that it spawns a subshell for every character, and assumes ASCII/UTF8.

---

## edit

@Shawn pointed out that you don't need the subshell -

```
while read -r -N 1 c; do printf "%%<%02X>" \'$c; done <<< AaAa
```

I noticed that these are leaving the string terminator in your output, though, and realized I could eliminate that and the `read` by assigning the data to a variable and using the built-in parsing tools.

```
$: x=AaAa && for((i=0;i<${#x};i++)); do printf "%%<%02X>" \'${x:i:1}; done; echo
%<41>%<61>%<41>%<61>
```

Comment: As written, this won't run on the POSIX shell (`/bin/sh`). It also has an upper bound on the size of the input. These may or may not be issues.

Comment: If you want *just* bash, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67870452/take-first-16-character-and-covert-it-into-hex-string/67874337#67874337

Comment: `bash` was explicitly mentioned.

Comment: You don't need the second `printf` in the pure bash version... `printf "%%<%02X>" "'$c"` works.

Comment: This variant of the first should work for larger inputs: `od -A n -t x1 <<<"AaAa" | xargs printf "%%<%s>"`

Comment: The ARG_MAX limit only applies to external programs, but printf is a bash built-in, so the size of the hexdump shouldn't be a problem (unless it so big that it does not fit into RAM).

Comment: I was also getting the string terminator. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

A simple Perl substitution would do the trick:

```sh
echo -n AaAa | perl -pe's/(.)/ sprintf "%%<%02X>", ord($1) /seg'
```

Shorter:

```sh
echo -n AaAa | perl -ne'printf "%%<%02X>", $_ for unpack "C*"'
```

In both cases, the output is the expected

```
%<41>%<61>%<41>%<61>
```

(No trailing line feed added. If you want one, append `; END { print "\n" }`.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
echo -n AaAa | perl -ne 'for $c (split//) { printf("%%<%02X>", ord($c)); }'
```

Output

```
%<41>%<61>%<41>%<61>
```

Comment: is the result of this processable through pipes as well? since you replied first i would flag yours as answer then, but right now i am getting odd behavior in WSL

Comment: @Dbl Yeah, it should work fine through pipes. I actually used WSL when writing the oneliner. What's odd about the result?

Comment: the formatting is off, but maybe thats a wsl problem

Comment: @Dbl Hmm, it looks as expected for me.  How is the formatting off?

Comment: WSL is not an OS. I use Ubuntu (over WSL), and it works fine. There's nothing OS-specific about that command (though you'd have to adjust quoting for the Windows `cmd` shell).

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe to `sed` to wrap each byte in `%<>` and then remove the whitespace.

```
echo -n "AaAa" | od -A n -t x1 | sed -E -e 's/[a-z0-9]+/%<&>/g' -e 's/ //g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `awk`

```
echo -n "AaAa" |
od -A n -t x1 |
awk 'BEGIN { ORS = "" } { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i+=1) print "%<"$i">"}'
```